# Realizar peticion ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, post

tengo ciertas dudas sobre como hacer una peticion ajax correctamente,necesito guardar estos valores dentro de data:

Pero no sé como plantearlo correctamente, todavía estoy aprendiendo.

Mi idea es que al realizar un "post" guarde los valores de(formularios,actual_step de sunbeds y total_sold)por dia para cuando yo haga un "get" seleccione el dia deseado y recupere los valores de ese dia.

Trabajo: https://codepen.io/Kawasaki93/pen/NWyJdVx

```
//"current_data","#form",sunbed "actual_step","total_sold".

        var conection;
    
    $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: '.../cr4id3r/sunbeds/blob/5875a09c7e6bdb9d8e3bb43f58ecf0d840395111/Conection.php',
               data:{
                 ("#current_date");
                 $('#form').serialize();
                  "actual_step": actual_step;
                  "total_sold": total_sold;
    
    
    
    },
               success: function (data) {
                     alert(data.Message);
               },
               error: function () {
                      alert("Error!!!");
               }
          });
          return false;
    
    });
```

Comment: Hola, dos cosas, revisando tu código he encontrado un error, el primero es que en la opción `data` concretamente en `('#current_date')...` está mal definida, debe de tener la siguiente forma: `valor que será recogido en el  post: valor del form`, otra cosa, en la función `error` ¿tienes definida la variable Message?, por penúltimo, el link de codepen está roto, arroja un error 404 al intentar acceder, revísalo, actualízalo y me dices y ya por último, te recomendaría revisar cómo formular una pregunta en stackoverflow, porque no nos deja muy claro el objetivo cómo tal de la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Por otra parte, revisando la opción `url` veo que está mal expresado, pues has puesto `...` a modo de (imagino) salir del directorio y acceder a  `/cr4id3r/sunbeds/blob/5875a09c7e6bdb9d8e3bb43f58ecf0d840395111/Conection.php`, para salir debes de usar únicamente dos puntitos, quedaría algo así `../cr4id3r/sunbeds/blob/5875a09c7e6bdb9d8e3bb43f58ecf0d840395111/Conection.php`

Comment: Hola @low_aortical_supremassy, primero que todo gracias por contestar, he modificado el link de mi trabajo y aplico la corrección que me comentas, mi idea es que guarde los valores por dia ,me gustaria que a la hora de realizar un get yo seleccione el dia deseado y recupere los valores de ese dia, tengo el ajax por separado en : https://codepen.io/Kawasaki93/pen/YzaqKjG